# Passing variables to CSS file in Django

Tags: css, django, django-templates

Is it possible to pass variables in CSS files, like in HTML file. Example:

In views.py:

```
def home(request):
    bgcolor = "#999"
    ...
    ...
```

In the CSS file:

```
body {
    background-color : {{bgcolor}};
}
```

If yes, can you please guide me how to achieve this? I would really appreciate. Thank you!

Edit: Ok, my bad. What I meant was, how do  let users customize their page if they wanted to? I suppose I could have done this without using external stylesheet, but I think CSS is served fastest if it's static and on a CDN and not using a template and CPU resources to render. Please guide me if there's a way to achive this.

Comment: did you find any solution to the above query as i am also having a similar requirement.

Answer (score 7):

This is a old question but I thought I'd help others as I also wanted to do this and I found a solution.

Instead of using a normal link tag specifying your stylesheet, use style tags and include your css file inline.

```
<style>{% include 'my.css' %}</style>
```

Then you can put jinja code in your css file and it will render the variables.  Useful if you want to allow users to customize colors etc.

Answer (score 5):

That's not the way to do this sort of thing. You should define different classes in the CSS file, then use then in your template dependent on the variables there.

Comment: I am sorry, I am confused. How do I define my own css classes and use it? Please see the Edit.

Answer (score 3):

you can pass the css style attribute adding the following line in your html page.

```html
 <div class="profile-cover" style="background: url('{{ cover }}')">
```

added attribute to css class provile-cover ***style="background: url('{{ cover }}')"***

{{ cover }} is the variable rendered from views.py to the HTML page using the urls.py

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. What if you need to pass a color from the View like `background-color : {{bgcolor}};`, as the question asked?

Comment: this will be correct way to use it      background-color : "{{bgcolor}}"

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Daniel Roseman's answer, but if you -really- need to do this you can just define your CSS in the template and use the python variable as shown there.

Another option is to see if you can use [mako templating](http://www.makotemplates.org/) if you can get it to work with Django.

But, unless you have some unusual compelling reason you need to do this, define your own CSS classes.

Comment: Ok... But I am confused. How do I define my own css classes and use it?

Comment: It's a fundamental part of CSS. See http://www.cssbasics.com/chapter_3_css_class.html for explanation.

Comment: I'm also going to throw this one at you, because it's how I and many others learned the basics of HTML/CSS http://www.w3schools.com/

Comment: Oh! I am sorry. I have edited above. What I meant was, how do I let users customize their page if they wanted to? I suppose I could have done this without using external stylesheet, but I think CSS is served fastest if it's static and on a CDN and not using a template and CPU resources to render. I hope, I made myself clear. Please guide me if there's a way to achive this.

Comment: If you mean different skins, try this: https://github.com/lethain/django-userskins.  If you mean something else, like a wysiwyg editor, I'm not sure, I'm 90% a backend developer.

Comment: Ok I will check on it. Thanks though!